# I have to find a missing number from a list just using for loop, see the code once i think you will understand

Tags: python

```
def missing_num(lst):
  lst=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
  for n in range(1,11):
    if n not in lst:
      print(n)
    else:
      print("Nothing is missing")

missing_num(lst)
```

#if you will answer then it will be a big help for me.

it is showing name error.

Comment: You need to assign `lst` outside the function if you want to use it as an argument.

Comment: Your algorithm is also wrong. You'll print `Nothing is missing` for each number that's not missing. You can't tell if nothing is missing unless you make it through the entire range.

Comment: You're also hardcoding the range rather than using the length of the input list

Comment: is your `lst` always suppose to have the numbers starting from 1? and is it always going to be ordered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Define your list(`lst`) outside the function
2. Use a `for/else` statement as shown [here](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html) to get a result of what's missing only **after the for ends**.
   The `else` part of the code runs if a `break` isn't found and the `for` reaches it's natural end.

**Full code**

```py
lst=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10]
def missing_num(lst):
    for n in range(1,11): 
        if n not in lst: 
            print(n)
            break
    else: 
        print("Nothing is missing")

missing_num(lst)
```

If you need to show all the numbers that are missing, there are a number of ways.
I would go for:

```py
lst=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,10]
def missing_num(lst):
    l = []
    for n in range(1,11): 
        if n not in lst:
            print(n)
            l.append(n)
    if not l: # if list is empty
        print("Nothing is missing")
missing_num(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

1.When you pass a `list` to a function, it must be defined outside of that particular function.

2.If the `size` of your list is 10 your code will print `nothing is missing` 10 times ie while checking every index even before reaching the end of the list.

3.Print `nothing is missing` only after checking all the elements in the list for which you can have a variable count the missing numbers.

You can try this:

```
def missing_num(lst):
  flag=0
  for n in range(1,11):
    if n not in lst:
      print(n," is missing")
      flag+=1                            #flag to count no of missing numbers 
    else:
      continue
  if(flag==0):                          # when flag is 0 print "no missing numbers"
      print("Nothing is missing")

lst=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
missing_num(lst)
```